# Character formatting/styling in cells' substrings using python in excel files

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl, xlwings

I am searching for a quite a long time to achieve formatting for characters in text except using vba...

like this:

***A***DSG***PIND***TDAN***PR***

RGT***EL***DDGIQADSGPINDTDAN***P***RY VPGYY ES***Q***SDDPHFHEK

but I am using mac and can't go with some answers I have found like

[this](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1458)

Answer if you know how to do this on a Mac.

Comment: In theory, you'd use the native `characters` property. But the underlying AppleScript broke that behavior, so it doesn't work correctly on macOS.

Comment: what do you mean by correctly?

Comment: Your answer works for only the beginning of the word. Try something like `characters[30:35]` and it will be off. This describes the issue: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/applescript-and-excel-problem/6e5a50b1-6209-4fbf-91f4-6d6674f1e488

Comment: @Felix Zumstein Yes you are right it doesn't work accurately for longer sequences, but what can be done for this?

Comment: One option would be to call a VBA macro from xlwings that takes care of this functionality. Not beautiful, but unless Microsoft fixes this bug, probably the only solution....

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use range.characters.font as described in [this documentation](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/0.28.3/api.html#characters), and it also worked on my mac...

I tried to make characters' font bold, italic and it worked like it should.

Also changing font colors also works using RGB code.

But what didn't work was changing the font size of individual characters.

below is the code...

```
testFileSheet.range("A1").characters[1:7].font.color = (60, 170, 0)
testFileSheet.range("A1").characters[1:7].font.bold = True
testFileSheet.range("A1").characters[1:7].font.italic = True
```